# Jdatabase : Counting number of elements in a comma separated field

Tags: mysql, jdatabase

I have a `Jdatabase`table having a *comma separated field*. What would be the best way (according to **Joomla coding standards**) to count the number of elements separated by commas. Like in the case below :

`id` `comma separated values`

`01` `(2,5,6,7,8,9,21,24,28)`

It should return : **9**

If I am not wrong, one of the ways to achieve it using `mysql` would be this :

```
SELECT (LENGTH(column_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_name,",","")) + 1) AS MyColumnCounts
FROM table_name;
```

But is this the best way?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally I would select the entire thing then use PHP to explode the values into an array, then count the array values. May not be the best approach though

Comment: I trust you, kindly write it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$id = 20; // Example ID

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->qn('roll_no'))
      ->from($db->qn('#__table_name'))
      ->where($db->qn('Id') . ' = '. $id);
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();
```

Then explode the result into an array, like so:

```
$array = explode(',', $result);
```

Then count the items in the array, like so:

```
$count = count($array);
```

Comment: Please note this is a personal preference. I'm not a backend developer so there's probably a better method

Comment: Still a far more better approach than what I thought. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specifically about Joomla, and it isn't far from how I'd recommend doing it.

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76c355c/2)

```
SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(csv) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(csv, ',', '')) + 1) AS num_of_commas
```

`CHAR_LENGTH()` is slightly more reliable versus `LENGTH()`.  [If/When you try to process multi-byte characters with `LENGTH()` you will generate incorrect results.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14635320/2943403)

Of course, if you wish to see the raw query translated to a Joomla `select()` method call, there isn't much to change:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select("SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(" . $db->qn("column_name") . " - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(" . $db->qn("column_name") . ", ',', '')) + 1) AS MyColumnCounts")
            ->from($db->qn("table_name"));
```

If your table_name/column_name values do not contain a space, are not MySQL reserved keywords, and are not supplied from untrustworthy sources (user-submitted), then you can safely omit the `$db->qn()` calls.